Flow Core Send Email action "Log on Send" to custom object - email renders as Task in Activity Timeline
I have a Flow that uses the Core Action Send Email.

It sends an HTML email (rich text body)
The recipients are email addresses, not a Contact or Lead
The Core Action is configured to Log on Send
Related Record Id is a custom object Foo__c
Email sends fine to recipient; rendered in HTML

But, on the Activity Timeline for the Foo record, while there is an entry for the Email (icon is the envelope), when the activity time entry is clicked, the SFDC user sees the email rendered as if it is a Task record, with the HTML markup appearing in the Task Comments field.

Email does not render as an email (Message sub tab), nor in HTML

Why is this happening?

This is what happens when you're working on an org that is still transitioning from Classic to Lightning.
Root cause:

Org did not have Setup > Enhanced Email enabled.

Enabling will cause any future emails sent by that Flow to render in the custom object's Activity Timeline as emails, not tasks.  Past emails render as Tasks.
